# Android unit test performLongClick() for ListView not triggering the OnItemLongClickListener()

Tags: android, unit-testing, listview, android-alertdialog

I'm using a `ListView` in my Android application. When user perform `onItemLongClick()` on the list items, an `AlertDialog.Builder` menu shows up. I'm writing unit test to test the above feature. The below code

```
mListView.performLongClick();
```

is not triggering the `OnItemLongClickListener()` of the `ListView`. `Robotium` is not an option for me as of now. Any help will be appreciated?

Answer (score 5):

```
   mListView.performLongClick();
```

performs long click on the list view, not on individual list item view.

use

```
listView.getOnItemLongClickListener().onItemLongClick(parent, view, position, id);
```

to perform long click on individual item

Comment: Hi Gopal Rao, `OnItemLongClickListener()` is a class and is not performing the click.

Comment: have you set OnItemClickListener to listview using listView.setOnItemClickListener(...)?

Comment: Yes, I've already set it in the list view. I'm not able to access it from my unit test file.

Comment: sorry, previously I said OnItemClickListener, but it is OnItemLongClickListener. have you set OnItemLongClickListener to ListView?

Comment: Yes, I've set the `OnItemLongClickListener()` to `ListView'.